# React native app cannot be installed at Android 9.0

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

As the question title said, my react native app cannot run at Android 9.0. Error occurs when installing, the error prompts with "There was a problem parsing the package". [It is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ6NZ.png)

I have no idea with what I can do. Just search many times via Internet but no likely answers can be found.

My android/build gradle file:

```html
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
/*configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}*/

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

My android/app/build.gradle:

```html
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * Set up the keychain passwords in release builds.
 */
def getPassword(String currentUser, String keyChain) {
   def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
   def stderr = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
   exec {
       commandLine 'security', '-q', 'find-generic-password', '-a', currentUser, '-s', keyChain, '-w'
       standardOutput = stdout
       errorOutput = stderr
       ignoreExitValue true
   }
   //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
      stdout.toString().trim()
}
def pass = getPassword("YBT","android_keystore")

configurations.all {
    /*resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    }*/
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ybtclient"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 140
        versionName "1.4"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword pass 
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword pass 
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.*'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    } 
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-share')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile project(':RCTWeChat')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    //implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-community-netinfo')
    // Automatically selecting the latest available version
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My package.json file:

```html
{
  "name": "YBTClient",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^3.1.0",
    "fuse.js": "^3.4.4",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "native-base": "^2.10.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.57.8",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.21.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.24.3",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-fcm": "^16.2.4",
    "react-native-immutable": "0.0.4",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-multiple-tags": "0.0.4",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-share": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-tab-navigator": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-tags": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-timer": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-wechat": "^1.9.10",
    "react-native-wheel-datepicker": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-zhb-actionsheet": "^1.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-number-format": "^4.0.8",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "tinycolor2": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Expected Result:
Can install at Android 9.0 Devices and run the app.
Actual Result:
Prompt Errors when installing the apk.

Comment: it would be nice to provide the error completely, so others can track the issue

Comment: you can change this `ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }`

Comment: or You can try upgrade `react-native version 0.59.+`

Comment: @BlueTurtle I have added the screenshot above.

Comment: @hongdevelop I have tried both ways you suggested but another errors occurs while I try to generate the apk.

Comment: what is error??

Comment: @hongdevelop Once I change the bulildToolVersion to 28.0.3, then have errors with the below message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':@react-native-community_netinfo:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3.

Comment: @hongdevelop And if I upgrade react-native from 0.57.8 to 0.59.9, it will have errors with below message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/joshua/react-native/ybt-agent/YBTAgent/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' line: 95

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

Comment: You try add app.gradle `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3`